# Design for three classes with partially shared logic

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, composition

I am looking for a suitable design which uses composition to allow three classes to share some logic.

The problem I am solving is that I have to read 3 different json configuration files from my application, and each file needs to have a different class that allows to filter specific data accordingly, however I need to share the logic of reading the files from the filesystem and validating the schema and format. I am looking to avoid inheritance and use composition instead, and I am trying to avoid repeating code as much as possible.

The three classes I currently have are:

```
CompanyConfig
  getCompanies()
  getCompany()

RoleConfig
  getRoles()
  getRole()
  getRolesBy()

ThemeConfig
  getThemes()
  isThemeEnabled()
```

On each of these classes constructors I am using a class LoadFileContents and ValidateFileContents, however the logic to invoke these two classes repeats on each of the config classes.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see a point to factoring out the logic around invoking the two utility classes. I can't imagine that they take more than a couple of lines of code each. Repeating 6 lines of code across three different classes is not a crime. Yet ...

Comment: Beware of the DRY police, they're after you! Seriously, wanting to avoid using a config file loader in separate places where configurations are needed is like wanting to avoid addition since you already used it in another function. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Doesn’t that break the SRP since my classes will have more than one reason to change?

Comment: Nothing wrong with violating design principles really;  the main factor in maintainability and code quality is automated test coverage rather than the structure of the code itself;  that is to say, if you ever need to revisit the code later on in future then the extent of your test coverage will primarily determine how easy or difficult it is for somebody to understand it, reason over it and change it.

Comment: *"the logic to invoke these two classes repeats on each of the config classes"* - could you give us an example of this logic, to give us an impression if it is really worth the effort of making the code DRY here?

Comment: ... I also took the freedom to remove the unnecessary word "pattern" from the question: you are obviously looking for a design, not necessarily a "design pattern". Several of our community members seem to automatically downvote every question which asks for a "design pattern".

Comment: "Nothing wrong with violating design principles really"   Principles are not so much "violated" as applied in thoughtful measure for design goals. Take Factory Pattern's scope ( I said 'pattern'!) - "factory method" , "factory class", "abstract factory".  Seems like carte blanche to infuse SRP in various abstractions (levels of).  Final thought: to declare <my pet principle> as inviolable despite the [totality of your  software's goals](https://dl.acm.org/doi/book/10.5555/203406), is the only real design principle violation.

Answer (score 3):

There is no design pattern for this. There are as many ways to do this as there are developers on this planet, so go for the most obvious design first.

In this case, you have 3 classes that read data from a file, validate the file format, and return strongly typed objects. Inheritance is an option here. The guideline is "favor composition over inheritance" not "don't use inheritance." The litmus test for whether or not inheritance is an appropriate solution is the "is a" test:

> **ChildClass** is a **ParentClass**

If you insert your own class names into the sentence above, and the sentence is still logically true, then inheritance might be a valid solution. Having an abstract **Config** class with one derived type for roles, companies and themes passes this test:

> **CompanyConfig** is a **Config**
>
> **RoleConfig** is a **Config**
>
> **ThemeConfig** is a **Config**

All three sentences make logical sense. Put the common logic in an abstract parent class.

Comment: `Config` is not a thing if it doesn't have behavior on its own. Inheritance is _not_ for sharing "utility" methods among subclasses. The OP is right to go for composition here. Also there should never be inheritance if there is no need for polymorphism.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam: I mostly agree with what you are saying. Within the realm of configuration, though, I'm just not sure if being this picky about inheritance is worth it. I do disagree that inheritance is only for polymorphism. It is also valid to use inheritance for specialization, which I consider to be related to, but different from polymorphism. Sub types can extend or build on the behavior of the parent type, even if no abstract members are present in the parent type. I was coming from this angle in my answer.

Comment: I must strongly agree with *"Inheritance is not for sharing "utility" methods among subclasses"*, though, if sharing utility methods is the *only* reason for the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [@Greg](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/118878/greg-burghardt) above.

As an additional point, consider moving the common functionality of I/O and validation out to separate classes.

Further, utilize abstract base classes for them and then compose them into the config classes (if a reader and validator **makes sense to be a component** of a config in your model).

This will help you attain several aspects of **SOLID** design, the key aspects being Single Responsibility and Dependency Inversion.

The advantages of such a split are:

- SRP and changes across the classes will not pollute one another (your colleagues will thank you during reviews).
- Config classes will focus on hierarchy and logic for transforming configs (business and product can keep making changes to this class, allow you to focus on more testing for this)
- If composing the I/O and validation classes into the config classes, you can sub it out for more specific implementations of them (utilize **O** and **L** of SOLID - Open and closed principle and Liskov Subsitution Principle)
  (This will allow existing classes using old readers to avoid any changes)

Hope that helps.